# Calculating 'hat' matrix in R

Tags: r, lm, least-squares

In calculating the 'hat' matrix in weighted least squares a part of the calculation is

```
X^T*W*X
```

However, I am unsure how one would do this in R

See the following example:

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=T)
xt <- t(x)
w <- as.vector(c(7,8,9))

xt*w%*%x
```

Which gives the error:

```
Error in xt * w %*% x : non-conformable arrays
```

Is there anything basic I have misunderstood?

EDIT

```
xt%*%w%*%x
```

gives the error:

```
Error in xt %*% w %*% x : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: You only used matrix multiplication for one of the multiplications.

Comment: w would need to be 3x3 for this to work. Do you want your three values to be on the diagonal of a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: As Dason said, you'll need `xt %*% diag(w) %*% x` here as `w` needs to be a diagonal matrix by definition.

Comment: Aha ! Yeah I just realized that also after reading your comments. Thank you. If you want to write it as an answer I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` needs to be 3x3 so make use `diag` to construct w as a matrix with those values on the diagonal instead of using a vector

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=T)
xt <- t(x)
w <- diag(c(7,8,9))

xt %*% w %*% x
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little rusty on regressions but I think the `hatvalues` function is what you are looking for. `?hatvalues` provides a useful of other diagnostics.

Comment: I only need X^T*W*X, so I just need to know how to get that part working either "manually" or by some function

Answer (score 1):

In your R code, w is a vector. It should be a diagonal matrix:

Replace this line:

```
w <- as.vector(c(7,8,9))
```

by this:

```
w <- as.vector(c(7,8,9))*diag(3)
```

Comment: All OP needs to do is `w <- diag(7:9)`